# Lots of "Unknown" crashes in Dev center

Tags: uwp, windows-dev-center

Just been looking at the Microsoft developer center and I checked the "Health" of a recently released application. Unfortunately it's not a nice sight with around 800 crashes in the last 30 days. What's even worse is 95% of these crashes are marked as "Unknown" with no stack trace or any information to help with sorting out the issue. See screenshot below:

[image]

What can I do about this, I need more information to try and fix any crashes there are in the app?

Comment: Have you tried downloading the failure reports ? they usually have additional information about the error.

Comment: That failure name "Unknown" isn't clickable, unlike all the others which provide a Failure Log and can actually get a stack trace.

Comment: Debug you aw pp in release mode, and try every option in your app and look into output window it will show you where is exception occurs and may be you will find exception related to xaml

Comment: This won't tell me which exception is the "Unknown" crash shown in the Dev center. Also what you are implying is, that I haven't tested my app which certainly isn't the case. I test the features I write and a team of testers test scenarios out of the scope of my feature, to ensure nothing is broken. These sort of application metrics are used to find user issues and edge case scenarios that users sometimes find

Answer (score 0):

> What can I do about this, I need more information to try and fix any
>   crashes there are in the app?

To get more information, you could upload your app to [Hockey app](https://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-windows-and-windows-phone/hockeyapp-for-applications-on-windows), which can help to manage testers, distribute apps and collect crash reports.

The servers of Hockey App could provide more powerful crash analytic report which can give you meaningful stack traces with class names, methods and accurate line numbers.

Comment: I'm using HockeyApp as well, in there we have Task Exception crashes with  no stack trace and also HockeyApp.Extensibility crashes with a stack trace which is essentially useless. Both crash analytics, at the moment, are as useless as each other. This is not an answer to my question, anyway you could find out what all these "Unknowns" are and if Microsoft is doing anything about them?